# 4 quotes always give different result in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've been googling for a couple of hours and I still don't understand a single thing about escaping quotes in sql.

Can somebody please explain me if  `''''` in sql means `'` why does `select '('||''''||')'` give `(')` why not `(''')`?

Comment: `''''` > the first and last quote denote the actual string, the middle two quotes denote a single quote - escaping quotes in strings is done by pairing them up, so you end up with a literal value of a single quote. You already state `''''` means `'` so what about concatenating `(` to `'` to `)` is confusing?

Comment: manual 4.1.2.4 the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in SQL must be enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `'a'`

A single quote inside a SQL string is escaped by doubling it: `''` - to create a string out of that, you need to enclose that in two single quotes: `''''` - so the `''` in the middle of that string are the same as the `a` in my first example.

The expression: `'('||''''||')'` consists of three string constants:

1. `'('` --> `(`
2. `''''` --> `'` (as explained above)
3. `')'` --> `)`